# Loggregator - Doppler and Traffic Controller

Tags: cloud-foundry

I read that Doppler is used for emitting logs into 3rd party log management systems such as splunk / paper trail whereas traffic controller is responsible for handling cf logs requests. Is the logs emitted by both components the same? If so why are 2 components created for emitting the same logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that Doppler is used for emitting logs into 3rd party log management systems such as splunk / paper trail whereas traffic controller is responsible for handling cf logs requests.

Correct.

> Is the logs emitted by both components the same? If so why are 2 components created for emitting the same logs?

The tasks are a bit different.  If you want to send logs to a 3rd party log system, you're pushing logs to that platform.  Doppler will do this for you as it receives the logs.  Actually, in newer versions of Loggregator logs don't go directly from Doppler to the 3rd party service.  They go through a reverse log proxy & the scalable syslog adapter, which is what interfaces with the actual 3rd party service.

If you want to get logs with `cf logs`, you're pulling logs.  That is the job of the traffic controller.  It takes the requests from the `cf` CLI and responds to them.  It makes this work easier for the CLI because it handles aggregating logs from possibly multiple Doppler servers.  This would be hard for the CLI, so traffic controller does this and provides an easy API through which the `cf` CLI can pull logs for you.

[This diagram explains the flows better](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator/blob/develop/docs/loggregator-design.md).  The document also explains the design of Loggregator in more depth.

Hope that helps!